# PWA Setup on local windows machine

Tags: magento, progressive-web-apps, magento-2.3, magento2.2, magento2.1

I want to setup PWA on my local windows machine but facing some problems.

Comment: I have an idea, tell what those problems are. It's usually bit easier to solve them that way than trying to be a mind reader.

Comment: what's the problem? It's possible, PWA doesn't relate to magento only

Comment: yarn install is not working. Getting an error: yarn is not an external and internal command.